# How do I remove jQuery Conflict in prototype.js with 1.11.1.jquery.min.js

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery

I have a conflict between jQuery and another library. I added the code below to the local.xml file as per answers found here.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
             <reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs" name="jquery" as="jquery">
        <script>jquery-1.11.1.js</script>
    </action>
    <action method="addJs">
        <script>noconflict.js</script>
    </action>
</reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

The answer said that the noconflict.js file should simply contain the following code.

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

I do not understand where I have to add the noconflict.js file. Is it to the js folder on the server? If the answer is *yes*, how do I create a JavaScript file?

Answer (score 4):

You can always bypass the noConflict() method by wrapping your jQuery in an IIFE: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/.

```
(function($){
    //use your jQuery code here
})(jQuery);
```

OR just use jQuery instead of $.

Answer (score 0):

Include the jquery.noConflict in the `app/design/frontend/default/[theme name]/template/page/html/head.phtml` file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict(); //Use no conflict here instead of js file
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

See details via following link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: in the header.phtml right?

Comment: @shamz head.phtml, not header.phtml

Comment: i did the same but doesnt seem to work though....

Answer (score 0):

In the file `jquery-1.11.1.js`, add `jQuery.noConflict();` at last.